# error al crear un nuevo proyecto de angular

Tags: angular

**saben porque me da este error al crear una nueva app en angular?. busque por todos lados y no se a que se debe el error, estoy usando Debian por si es que influye en algo?.
Ya probe con "npm cache clean" y me da el mismo error.**

```
⠹ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peer typescript@"~4.0.0 || ~4.1.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">=4.0 <4.2" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"11.1.1" from @angular/localize@11.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!       peerOptional @angular/localize@"^11.0.0 || ^11.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     1 more (ng-packagr)
npm ERR!   1 more (ng-packagr)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@"~3.9.5" from tsickle@0.39.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tsickle
npm ERR!   peerOptional tsickle@"~0.39.0" from ng-packagr@11.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/ng-packagr
npm ERR!     peerOptional ng-packagr@"^11.0.0 || ^11.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/juan/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/juan/.npm/_logs/2021-01-31T02_36_35_925Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

**********probe algunas cosas que me recomendaron y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, me da otros errores y algunos son los mismos. 
Adjunto los resultados que me devolvio la terminal, me devolvio los siguientes errores:  **********

```
juan@Debian:~/Descargas/angular$ npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
npm ERR! by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
npm ERR! data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
npm ERR! want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
npm ERR! instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
npm ERR! not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
npm ERR! or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
npm ERR! cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
npm ERR! temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm ERR! with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/juan/.npm/_logs/2021-01-31T03_13_28_338Z-debug.log
juan@Debian:~/Descargas/angular$ npm upgrade npm@latest

up to date, audited 1 package in 387ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
juan@Debian:~/Descargas/angular$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! dest /opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-RDVdZAKv
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' -> '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-RDVdZAKv'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' -> '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-RDVdZAKv'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli',
npm ERR!   dest: '/opt/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-RDVdZAKv'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/juan/.npm/_logs/2021-01-31T03_21_31_344Z-debug.log
```

ya busque por varios lugares y encuentro errores similares, los pruebo y no me dan resultado

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas `npm install -g` en cualquier plataforma y obtienes el error `EACCES` es por que estas escribiendo o renombrando un directorio al cual no tienes acceso, por lo cual tu ordenador lo rechaza.

Veo que estas utilizando Debian, asi que algunos te recomendarían usar `sudo npm install -g` para solucionarlo, pero puede ser que eso te cause problemas en un futuro en las dependencias.

Mejor te comparto un link con la [documentación de npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) paso a paso, para resolver el error `EACCES`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes abrir el directorio que acabas de crear con ng new, abrir el archivo que se llama package.json, ir a devDependencies.

Ahí como puedes ver esta lo que marca tu error, tu error dice que por ejemplo typescript  esta en 4.0  cuando debería ser 4.2, y así sucesivamente, en ese archivos podrás colocar lo que indica por consola, y luego de hacer los ajustes, guardas y vuelves a hacer npm install, y también te servirá el ng server.

Answer (score 0):

podes intentar un nuevo proyecto con:

```
$ npm cache clean -f
$sudo apt install python-software-properties
$curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
$sudo apt install nodejs
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
$ ng new hello-angular12
$ cd hello-angular12
$ ng serve
```